# Linux command line tool to read binary C++ objects

Tags: c++, linux

I am writing many instances of a C++ object (below) to file in binary.

```
struct Example
{
    double a, b;
    char c;
    Object d;
};
```

If I want to read this data from C++ I just `reinterpret_cast<Example>` and extract the members.

However, I'd like a non-programmer to be able to scroll and read the file, like the Linux program `less`. Unfortunately `less` doesn't understand the binary data of `Example`.

I know I could just have a C++ script which simply writes the binary file to an ASCII file but the data is large and cannot be re-written to disk.

What is the best way of achieving this?

Comment: Write a program that works like less. Use ncurses for the interface.

Comment: Also binary objects could be in many-many different open and proprietary formats. So I don't think there's a universal solution for your question. Just my two cents

Comment: Altenatively for writing the program like less, you can write a program that will read the file and output the result to less.

Comment: @KamilCuk I'm guessing your solution would be much simpler than writing my own Less?

Comment: Write a filter that formats the binary input to text, write it to stdout/cout. You can pipe it through less, it doesn't all have to fit in memory. The filter will just block when the pipe is full until less reads some more (use `less -B` if you really need to keep less' internal buffer under control, or just use `more` instead of `less` ...)

Comment: The traditional Unix solution is to make a small program that writes the textual interpretation to standard output. Then the user can pipe that into whatever tool they want.

Comment: I think it makes sense to clear _"However, I'd like a non-programmer to be able to scroll and read the file, like the Linux program `less`"_ Is it important to be able to scroll up and down like default `less` or is it enough to scroll down like default `more`? If you want to be able to scroll to the end and back to the beginning with `less` it has to store the complete output of your program somewhere.

Comment: _"By default, when data is read from a pipe, buffers are allocated automatically as needed. If a large amount of data is read from the pipe, this can cause a large amount of memory to be allocated. The -B option disables this automatic allocation of buffers for pipes, so that only 64K (or the amount of space specified by the -b option) is used for the pipe. Warning: use of -B can result in erroneous display, since only the most recently viewed part of the piped data is kept in memory; any earlier data is lost. "_ https://linux.die.net/man/1/less

Comment: @ThomasSablik I don't use More much, so yes if it allows the same scrolling, More is fine too.